# tool to generate JPA entity classes from a database schema at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement.

I want to generate the JPA entity classes from the database, details of which(like driver,  connection url, username/pswd, dialect) will be given at runtime. **No detail available at the design time**. I should also be able to generate DB schema from the JPA entity class.

I have gone through hibernate tools api but what I understood is; it will generate the POJO file and hibernate mapping file from the DB not the JPA entity class.

Any idea what tool/ api can be useful here, or if anyone has implemented that earlier?

Any sample code shall be highly appreciated.

Apologies in case I have missed something.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that this is really hard if you are using table inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using netbeans ide for creating entity classes from db. You can use already hibernate reverse engineering in netbeans or eclipse.

Comment: Pls correct me if I am wrong, you must be doing it at design time. However, what I need is at the runtime.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. You can call hbm2java at runtime, which is used by hibernate reverse engineering tools. And most tools provides selection if you want pojo and mapping file or entities with annonations.